# How can I set the default keyboard layout on startup in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, colemak

I have the [Colemak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colemak) keyboard layout downloaded and added to my layouts, but I can't figure out a way to make Colemak the default on startup.

Every time I shut and open my laptop, it resets to "English (United States) US Keyboard", instead of "English (United States) Colemak (Caps Lock unchanged)". How can I make Colemak the default?

I'm using Windows 10 on a laptop.

Comment: Did you select the Keyboard in Settings, Time and Language, Typing, Advanced Keyboard settings?

Answer (score 6):

Search for "Advanced Keyboard Settings" in the settings, then under "Override for input method" you can select your default layout.

[image]
[image: Override of default input method]

Comment: For future readers, can you [elaborate](https://superuser.com/posts/1760525/edit) on *"in the settings"*, for example, how to get there? An appropriate screenshot (for example, cropped, not too big, annotated with freehand circles and text, etc.) might also be a good idea. (But ****** ***without*** ****** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)